# url resolvers inside if statements Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-1.11, django-request

Just wondering what the correct syntax is for checking if the current path is equal to some url:

```
{% if request.path == url "app_namespace:route_name" %}
```

Above doesn't work - but hoping someone knows a way or method for doing this lookup...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Templates: Comparing current url with {% url xyz %}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7593669/django-templates-comparing-current-url-with-url-xyz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this syntax to save the url path in a template variable:

```
{% url 'app_namespace:route_name' as url_path %}
```

which you can later use within your `if` condition

```
{% if request.path == url_path %}...{% endif %}
```

Note that you may also find this syntax useful when you need to use the output of a `url` function within a [blocktrans](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/translation/#blocktrans-template-tag) block:

```
{% blocktrans %}
    <a href="{{ url_path }}">text to translate</a>
{% endblocktrans %}
```

Comment: Didn't quite work - 'app_namespace:route_name' is being interpreted as a string...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Well, yeah, you do have to check it against a hardcoded value, right? Otherwise, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: No - as in it’s just checking url_name == app_namespace:route_name ... I want to check it against what {% url app_namespace:route %} evaluates to.

Comment: I can't really figure out what exactly are you trying to accomplish here. You could also try with `{% url 'app_namespace:route_name' as url_path %}` and then use check against it with `{% if request.path == url_path %}`.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Please take a look - I updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome, glad to have helped.